# match exact attribute name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use **each** function, but I need to match the exact attribute name

jquery

```
$('[data*="name"]').each(function(i, obj){dostuff}
```

I need to **{dostuff}** only when  **name** is found and not when **names** is found.Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), which is basically identical to your current selector sans the `*` (as `*=` is used as a ["contains" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)) :

```
// This would perform your operation to every element that had a data attribute of
// "name" (i.e. <span data="name">, etc.)
$('[data="name"]').each(function(i, obj){ 
      dostuff(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

remove the *

```
$('[data="name"]').each(function(i, obj){dostuff}
```

according to the [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) the * matches also substrings, so just remove it if you don't need :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do it in that way.

```
$('[data="name"]').each(function(i, obj){ dostuff });
```

I hope I have helped you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
 $('[data="name"]').each(function(i, obj){dostuff}
```

OR

```
 $('[data*="name"]:not([data*=names])').each(function(i, obj){dostuff}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "contains" condition from the attribute selector (the * character)

```
$('[data="name"]').each(function(i, obj){dostuff}
```

Using the * after the attribute name

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given substring

Read [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)